# F# pattern match to a range of numbers

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I have a function getFullFitness

```
let getFullFitness population = 
     ResizeArray(population |> Seq.map snd) |> Seq.sum
```

and I pattern match in the function realTick

```
let realTick population = 
    match(getFullfitness population) with
    |(50) -> population
    | _ -> childGeneration population
```

Question is on the line |(50) -> population.  Since getFullFitness returns an integer sum, how do i match values between 0 and 50 in realTick?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One way is to use a guard -

```
|t when t < 50 -> ...
```

Answer (score 10):

In F#, a recommended way to pattern match on ranges is to use [active patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx). If we carefully manipulate pattern names, it will look quite close to what we want:

```
let (|``R0..50``|_|) i =
    if i >= 0 && i <= 50 then Some() else None

let realTick population = 
    match(getFullfitness population) with
    | ``R0..50`` -> population
    | _ -> childGeneration population
```

Pattern matching on ranges is supported in OCaml, but it's unlikely to be added to F#. See the related User Voice request at http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/6027309-allow-pattern-matching-on-ranges.

Answer (score 10):

If you are choosing between two ranges of numbers like in your example, I would
just use a `if-then-else` expression:

```
let realTick population =
  let fitness = getFullFitness population
  if 0 <= fitness && fitness <= 50 then
    population
  else
    childGeneration population
```

or a simple guard:

```
let realTick population =
  match getFullFitness population with
   | fitness when 0 <= fitness && fitness <= 50 ->
     population
   | _ ->
     childGeneration population
```

If your actual choice is much more complicated, then you might want to use
active patterns.  Unlike @pad, I would use a parameterized active pattern:

```
let (|BetweenInclusive|_|) lo hi x =
  if lo <= x && x <= hi then Some () else None

let realTick population =
  match getFullFitness population with
   | BetweenInclusive 0 50 ->
     population
   | _ ->
     childGeneration population
```

One higher-order active pattern I've found occasionally useful is a general
purpose predicate:

```
let (|Is|_|) predicate x =
  if predicate x then Some () else None
```

Using `Is` you could write something like this:

```
let lessEq lo x = x <= lo
let greaterEq hi x = hi <= x

let realTick population =
  match getFullFitness population with
   | Is (greaterEq 0) & Is (lessEq 50) ->
     population
   | _ ->
     childGeneration population
```

Note that, while something like this is overkill in a simple example like this,
it can be convenient in more complicated scenarios.  I personally used active
patterns similar to this to implement a simplification pass in an optimizing
compiler that pattern matched over a large number of cases of primitive
operations and properties of the parameters given to those primitives.